# Socket.io Multiple Live Pages

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have recently started using [socket.io](http://socket.io).

I want to show real time comments for any blog post, So what should I do?

1. Should I create multiple channels for each post? (If I use pusher)
2. Should I use multiple socket.io rooms for each post?

I know how [socket.io](http://socket.io) works in real time for two different browsers seeing same page but how to handle real time events on various web pages?

Comment: @ThomasBormans Thanks for editing the question.

Comment: What is the difference channels and rooms?

Comment: I've found these suggestion on google. I just wanted to know how socket.io handles real time dom manipulation on multiple pages.

Comment: If it is for a small site, I would just emit the message and filter on the client if the person is looking at the same post. If so, add the comment. If not, disregard the comment.

Comment: You need to pass a variable on conection (post identifier). Use the "post identifier" to create the room of the post and join the client to the room on connection. When a user leave a comment  in a post, emit message to this specific room : io.to('postId').emit('new comment'):

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo So that means i need to use Rooms in socket.io and channels in pusher.io